# Django QuerySet.union() -or- QuerySet.raw() to Achieve Case-Insensitive Mutli-Search

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, case-insensitive

Given a URL like this:

```
http://..../search/?foo=a&foo=B&bar=whatever
```

In my View, I want to filter the QuerySet for CASE-INSENSITIVE matches of "foo".  There's a handy "in" operator that I could use on my list of "foo", but it doesn't support case-insensitivity.

To be clear, this (elegant code) performs a CASE-SENSITIVE match.  (It doesn't match "foo=b".)  I do not want this:

```
    queryset = queryset.filter(foo__in=role)  # case-sensitive
```

My solution is to create a list of QuerySets, one for each "foo" match, and then to create return a final "union()" of the results.

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
  queryset = super(PeopleListView, self).get_queryset()

  foo = self.request.GET.getlist('foo')
  if (len(foo) == 1):
    queryset = queryset.filter(foo__iexact=role[0])  # case-insensitive
  elif (len(foo) > 1):
    qs_list = []
    for _foo in foo:
      qs_list.append(queryset.filter(foo__iexact=_foo))
    queryset = Person.objects.none()  # EmptyQuerySet
    for qs in qs_list:
      queryset = queryset.union(qs)

  bar = self.request.GET.get('bar')
  if bar is not None:
    queryset = queryset.filter(bar__iexact=bar)  # Easy
```

This results in an error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.
```

Is there a way to do this with "Q" objects?

If not, I think the "right" solution would involve converting the match patterns to lower-case, then using QuerySet::raw() to convert the database values to lower-case as well.  I'm a bit over my head there...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's the answer.  Use "Q" objects!  :-)

```
...
foo = self.request.GET.getlist('foo')
if (len(foo) > 0):
  q = Q()
  for _foo in foo:
    q |= Q(foo__iexact=_foo)
  queryset = queryset.filter(q)
...
```

Oh, and to support matching URLs like this:

```
http://..../fl/users/?foo=&bar=some_bar
```

which makes:

```
<QueryDict: {'foo': [''], 'bar': ['some_bar']}>
```

I'll do this:

```
...
foo = self.request.GET.getlist('foo')
if (len(foo) > 0):
  q = Q()
  for _foo in foo:
    if (_foo == ''):
      q |= Q(foo=None)
    else:
      q |= Q(foo__iexact=_foo)
  queryset = queryset.filter(q)
...
```

Comment: Do you have a ref. for the Django docs which illustrate how to do this?  I'm still a bit confused, but would like to read up on it.